# Convert world to normalized viewport

Tags: 3d, vtk

Is there a way to convert a *world point* into **normalized viewport** position ? How can I do that ? I saw how to convert world position to viewport, but not *normalized viewport* ... can you help me ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

-just change vtkRenderer with your renderer and vtkViewport with yourviewport

```
void WorldToView(double &x, double &y, double &z)
{
    double coordinates[3];
    coordinates[0]=x;
    coordinates[1]=y;
    coordinates[2]=z;

    vtkRenderer->SetWorldPoint(coordinates);
    vtkRenderer->WorldToView();
    vtkRenderer->GetViewPoint(coordinates);

    x = coordinates[0];
    y = coordinates[1];

    vtkViewport->ViewportToNormalizedViewport(x,y);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used VTK, however in most contexts the mathematical term *normalization* means converting an arbitrary quantity of some scale to a standard scale.

Lets say a value can range from 0 to 800 (may be pixel position or files to be copied or any other quantity). One way of normalizing this would be to make this interval fit within the interval [0, 100]. This is the famous percentage system used commonly, say when displaying a file copy dialog or when talking about the percentage of employees aged above 50, etc. The mapping between the actual and the normalized value would be determined by some scaling factor. 800 should map to 100% so `800 * s = 100` ⇒ `s = 1/8` i.e. multiplying any value in the given interval [0, 800] would map it to the range [0, 100].

Another normalized system may be formulated to have a target interval of [0, 1] instead of [0, 100]. This is quite common in graphics. When the intensity of a colour channel is a floating-point value, usually it's clamped to the interval [0, 1], 0 being the darkest and 1 being the brightest. Another common system having an interval of [0, 255] uses a byte to fit the intensity of a channel.

As per the [VTK documentation](http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/VTK-4.5/classvtkCoordinate.html), the interval for the normalized pixel is [0, 1]. So the scaling factor for you to convert a actual pixel value into a normalized pixel value would depend on the actual viewport size. For a viewport of size `800 × 600`, the scaling factors would be S<sub>x</sub> = 1/800, S<sub>y</sub> = 1/600.

> Is there a way to convert a world point into normalized viewport position ?

Yes, convert from world space to viewport space and then normalize the values to get the normalized viewport position. If there's helper functions which already does this (from *gele*'s answer it seems there're such functions already) for you, use them.